# Spacing and alignment in equations

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations

I didn't find a solution about how to add units to equations.

I have my code

```
\begin{equation}
  \eta = \frac{\Phi}{P}      [lm \cdot W^{-1}]
  \label{eq:mv}
\end{equation}
```

which is centered by default.
I need this:

1. Add some wide space (about 2 or 3 centimeters) between `\eta = \frac{\Phi}{P}` and `[lm \cdot W^{-1}]`.
2. Keep the alignment for the first part only `\eta = \frac{\Phi}{P}` so this would be centered and the other part would be right to it.

Can you give me a hint, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

You have:

\begin{equation}
  \eta = \frac{\Phi}{P}      [lm \cdot W^{-1}]
  \label{eq:mv}
\end{equation}

You want:

\begin{equation}
  \eta = \frac{\Phi}{P}     \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{3cm} $[\mathrm{lm} \cdot \mathrm{W}^{-1}]$}
  \label{eq:mv}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please observe that units are typeset in normal font, not the math one.

An alternative way of aligning is the option `fleqn`, changing centering of equations to common indentation of them.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this, slightly different, using the mathtools package (and SIunitx for units):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}   
\usepackage{mathtools}   
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}%  
You have: 

\begin{equation}  
  \eta = \frac{\Phi}{P}      [lm \cdot W^{-1}]  
  \label{eq:mv}  
\end{equation}

You want: 

\begin{align}  
\hspace{1in} \eta & = \frac{\Phi}{P} \hspace{1in} \mathllap{[\si{\lumen\watt^{-1}]}}  
  \label{eq:mv}  
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

which gives this:[image]

Comment: It's easier with `\mathrlap{\hspace{.5in}(\si{\lumen\watt^{-1}})}` and no `\hspace{1in}` at the left. Do you see why? The units should go in parentheses rather than in brackets, I believe.

Comment: Oh yes! My solution makes a gap of 1in minus the width of the unit – in the present case more or less ½in.